# VOID data type in C

Tags: c, type-conversion

If i declare any variable using `void`, it gives error but `sizeof(void)` is 1. 
What is reason for this?

```
void var; // it gives error
printf("sizeof(void) = %d", sizeof(void)); //prints 1
```

Comment: Probably just a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884061/cant-compile-with-void-variable-in-c -- the tl,dr is "there is no such thing in C".

Comment: I don't understand the question. What error is given? Is the problem that a variable of type `void` cannot be declared or that `sizeof(void)` evaluates to `1`?

Comment: That would actually make a nice question if you made a little effort formatting it properly.

Comment: Why you need `void` variable? If you want to reserve memory and use it for different data types, define `union` with corresponding members. `void` is for function return value (missing) or abstract pointer.

Answer (score 6):

`sizeof (void)` is not valid in C and is allowed in GNU C as an extension to allow pointer arithmetic with `void *`.

From `gcc` [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html):

> In GNU C, addition and subtraction operations are supported on pointers to void and on pointers to functions. This is done by treating the size of a void or of a function as 1. [...]  consequence of this is that sizeof is also allowed on void and on function types, and returns 1.

Answer (score 0):

The void type, in several programming languages derived from C and Algol68, is the type for the result of a function that returns normally, but does not provide a result value to its caller. Usually such functions are called for their side effects, such as performing some task or writing to their output parameters.
Upto my knowledge, You cannot use void as datatype, as the value is true or false statement the Boolean value will be 1 by default, so, it prints 1.

Answer (score 0):

c.f. Is there a specific reason why “void” was not simply defined as “typedef struct{} void” (i.e. an empty struct) with appropriate casting rules? ...

This was originally suggested by [Steve Bourne](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_R._Bourne) in [AB33/Mar 1972](http://archive.computerhistory.org/resources/text/algol/ACM_Algol_bulletin/1061601/p54-bourne.pdf) for [Algol68](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:ALGOL_68) ...

Note: Algol68 doesn't have pointer arithmetic... but array slicing is available.